# how to create content under a parent content?

Tags: umbraco

I m very new to Umbraco, my apologies if I m not using correct terminology.

I have created DocumentType *News* and using document type *news* I have created a content **News** which has URL like `domain/news/`

Then I created 2 child contents (**Breaking-News** and **Busienss-News**)  under this **News**. In Umbraco back office under content they appear as child elements of **News**

**What is issue**
Url of both child elements come as:
`domain/Breaking-news/` and `domain/Business-news/`

**What is Required**
Url of both child elements should be like:
`domain/NEWS/Breaking-news/` and `domain/NEWS/Business-news/`
Can you please guide me what I should do to achieve it.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All root items in Umbraco's Content section is seen as a root of the domain. So you will have to create another parent element to News.

What I always do, is to create a Frontpage (or Home) template. This will be my first level.
So you will have to do it like this:

```
Frontpage
- News
  - Breaking-news
    - news item
  - Business-news
    - a business news item
```